# limiting responses to ten Pentagonal numbers per line

Tags: c++, numbers, lines

I'm writing a code that requires pentagonal numbers to be limited to ten per line, however I can't get it to work. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getPentagonalNumber(int n)
{
    /*equation to calculate pentagonal numbers*/
    return (n * (3 * n - 1) / 2);
}

int main()
{
    /*Ask the user to put in the number of results*/
    int userInput;
    cout << "How many pentagonal numbers would you like to be displayed: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "results are: " << endl;

    /*Loop to generate the numbers for the equation*/
    for (int n = 1; n <= userInput; n++)
    {
        cout << getPentagonalNumber(n) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?  What do you expect to happen?  What does happen?

Comment: @NathanOliver Probably OP wants to display only 10 numbers per line, although the question is badly written.

Comment: @M. Johnathon Your code really doesn't do anything to handle your requirement of 10 numbers per line. You could simply test the `n` value for division 10 remainder and make a new line when zero.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getPentagonalNumber(int n)
{
    /*equation to calculate pentagonal numbers*/
    return (n * (3 * n - 1) / 2);
}

int main()
{
    /*Ask the user to put in the number of results*/
    int userInput;
    cout << "How many pentagonal numbers would you like to be displayed: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "results are: " << endl;

    /*Loop to generate the numbers for the equation*/
    for (int n = 1; n <= userInput; n++)
    {
        cout << getPentagonalNumber(n) << " ";
        if (n % 10 == 0)
           cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

?

I added a new line output every time  n is divisible by 10.